# How to get a subset of a range in C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I need to write some code using C# to remove Excel cell that does not contain any data other than formatting

[image: I want to check (A1:G13 - A1:B2) contains data other formating]

The idea is

1. get all cells contains data (format,string, anything) in a range object using

   ```
   int maxRow = workSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
   int maxColumns = workSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
   Range max = workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[1, 1], workSheet.Cells[maxRow, maxColumns]]
   ```
2. get another range object `Range offset = worksheet.Cells[2, 2]`
3. I want to get a new Range complement = (Excel.Range)(max - offset)
   In another word, I want to get the complement of Range offset.

Here is a bit of background information why I want to do this.
a. We need to convert a large amount of excel workbooks to html for processing.
b. Some excels workbooks contains thousands of columns/rows. There are no useful data in the cells except for formatting. The empty cells makes the converted html file very large.
c. We want to be able to identify the range that contains the useful data and the range that contains empty cells. We will clear format the empty cells to reduce the size of converted html files.

Comment: Could you copy the [a1:b2] range, do the cell removing process on the whole [a1:g13] range, paste back the [a1:b2] range?

Comment: So you want everything _except_ the cells that contain data?

Comment: "The idea is to get all cells contains data (format,string, anything) in a range object" - That is pretty much what the `UsedRange` is.  Are you getting something else from the  `UsedRange` ?

Comment: @ja72 Yes and no. 
I don't want to have a range of all cells.
I want to get the a range that of all cells that have blue background then check whether the range contains data except for format. If it does, I would expand the offset range until the blue range contains no data. I would remove the format and convert the excel files into html.

Comment: I still don't get it. Please edit the question and make it clear what the process is, and maybe add a simple example of the steps involved.

Comment: I think you just want to expand the range to include all data, but also any empty cells that fall within the rectagle of cells (for example A3 above).

Comment: @ja72 Thanks for taking look. I have edited the question and added additional background info. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Like how many rows and columns in this large data set?

Comment: @ja72 The files can contain more than 10000+ empty rows. The number of columns can be several hundreds. These empty data dramatically increase the converted html file size. It causes problem when we store the html file into mongodb.

Comment: I don't think there is an answer to this. Excel will not allow you to remove cells from a range area (rectangular region). You cannot create a range object with holes in it.

Comment: @ja72, I am not try to remove the cells.I just need to clear the format of the cells.  I will break it down to two different parts (in green) and check. thanks.https://screenpresso.com/=gP0Gf.